# Solutions To Get Around Records Per Page Parameters?

Tags: google-bigquery

So I'm trying to setup this script that pipes this data via an API into BigQuery.

It's all being done on the command line, and I've already successfully setup the framework behind it. Specifically, setting up the schema.json file.

When I run the following, it successfully uploads:

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON  --max_bad_records=10 program_users gs://internal/program_user.json program_users_schema.json
```

As I said, this successfully pipes into BQ, which is great. But the problem is, this API only allows a max of 50 records at a time when there are over 1000.

**EDIT:** The initial call to retrieve the records looks like this:

```
$ curl -s https://api.programs.io/users/57f263fikgi33d8ea7ff4 -u 'dG9rOmU5NGFjYTkwXzliNDFfNGIyJ24iYzA0XzU0NDg3MjE5ZWJkZD=': -H 'Accept:application/json'
```

Would anyone have a solution to this, particularly, one that is done in the command line?

Comment: why you think it allows max of 50 records? where you got this from?

Comment: as far as I know, you could insert a billion records this way

Comment: From the websites API documentation

Comment: What way are you talking about?

Comment: you most likely looking wrong doc - there is no limit here that would prevent you to load your 1K records, and as Felipe mentioned  - you can actually load billinons of record. What happens I think is that you are being cut becuase you have `max_bad_records=10` - so most likely you are getting this 10 bad records issue

Comment: My bad! Just realize I posted the wrong script. Well, technically it is one of the scripts I use, but I meant to post the actual API call itself, which I just edited my post to include. 

The API being used only allows a max of 50 records when I put that in

Comment: can you link to the documentation you are citing?